# PHP rewrite cookie value without lifetime reset

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I'm setting the cookie with life time till midnight comes.

```
setcookie('foo', 'bar', strtotime('today 23:59') );
```

How can I rewrite value of `['foo']` without resetting lifetime?
For example  `setcookie('foo', 'foo-bar', /* current lifetime*/ );`

How to get current lifetime of cookie with 'foo' key?

Comment: $_COOKIE['foo'] = 'abc'

Comment: @Sundar I think $_COOKIE is "system super global read-only" vairable.. The best solution I think up for now is to save json encoded array such as 

$time_to_set = strtotime('today 23:59');
$cookie = json_encode(array(
 'foo' => 'bar',
 'ttl' => $time_to_set,
));
setcookie('foo', $cookie, $time_to_set );

Comment: @Sundar , I think that you are wrong. Look here: [link](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/create-cookies-php-javascript)
**Actually, there is not a way to update a cookie. Just set (again) this cookie using setcookie.** so realy the best way to read ttl value is to set it inside array of our data that we wants to put inside cookie, make it json and set into it

Comment: Agreed. Cookie is read only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way:
save json encoded array such as

```
$time_to_set = strtotime('today 23:59');
$cookie = json_encode(array( 'foo' => 'bar', 'ttl' => $time_to_set, ));
setcookie('foo', $cookie, $time_to_set );
```

and to read cookie TTL:

```
$cooke_personal_ttl = json_decode($_COOKIE['foo'], true)['ttl'];
```

Or something like this..